# Introducing stars underneath phrase

Tags: bash

I am using this bash function to print a phrase with stars below it.
Am looking at how the implementation can be simplified?

```
outline ()
{ 
  titl="$1"
  n="${#titl}"
  
  # extract leading spaces
  [[ $titl =~ ^(\ )* ]]; spaces="${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
  
  # remove leading spaces from titl
  titl="${titl/#$spaces/}"
  
  echo "$spaces$titl"
  echo "$spaces${titl//?/*}"
}
```

Invoking the following commands

```
outline "Stack Exchange"
outline "   Stack Exchange"
```

results in

```
Stack Exchange
**************
   Stack Exchange
   **************
```

Comment: It might be easier to use underline or other formatting tools to make your text stand out (if that is what you intend to do). You can check out this link for comprehensive guide:

https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting

For example to underline your phrase try this:

echo -e "\e[4mStack Exchange\e[0m"

Comment: I find the line too thin for me.  Furthermore, the leading spaces also get underlined.

Comment: try echo -e "     \e[4mStack Exchange\e[0m"

Comment: A similar question was asked on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70149677/underline-with-stars-from-first-non-space-character) Good luck on your school project!